# How to use a third party js library in Angular 2 / Typescript application?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I am trying to use a third party .js library in Angular 2 / Typescript application. There are some examples on the web (like using declare var libraryVar: any;) but nothing seems to work. Is there a one correct way to integrate a .js library into a Typescript / Angular2 ?

Comment: What library?  Try TSD.

Comment: uuid.js I think I can find it on DefinitelyTyped but not sure what to do next.

Comment: tsd install uuid --save, 
bower install node-uuid --save, 
setup tsconfig.js file to ignore bower-components,

Answer (score 3):

> There are some examples on the web (like using declare var libraryVar: any;) but nothing seems to work. Is there a one correct way to integrate a .js library into a Typescript / Angular2

Perhaps you forgot to put the `declare var libraryVar:any;` in a *vendor.d.ts* file that has *no root level import/exports*.

More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/migrating.html

Answer (score 1):

The web is full of examples of typescript projects consuming 3rd party libraries.

[Here](https://github.com/ca0v/ags-lab) is one of mine which uses arcgis-js-api.

And [Here](https://github.com/ca0v/ol3-lab) is one that uses openlayers.

In your case you would try this:

```
bower init
bower install node-uuid --save
tsd install uuid --save
```

Then setup your [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json) file.  I think Angular 2 uses systemjs so you'd want to set module="system" (see [system](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options)) unless you have a reason not to.

I haven't had much luck with systemjs but you might need to do something like this to get it to load uuid or any other AMD modules:

```
window.define = System.amdDefine;
window.require = System.amdRequire;
```

See [system-api](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/system-api.md) for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to use an external library is to create a variable for it at the top of your typescript and import the js. By doing so the variable will offer all the functions the library provides inside your TS without any extra work.

for example if you want to use moment.js to do some time computation.
add this to your ts file

```
var moment = require("./scripts/moment");
```

after that you can use the functions inside your typescript by directly using the variable

```
moment.fromNow("SOMEDATE");
```

I faced the exact problem couple of days ago and I saw this is a good fit, Another neat way is to create a typescript class with all the helpers and reference the typescript to your file and call the helpers within. Still experimenting on a solid pattern, but this would be the start point.

Comment: I get this error when I try that: ReferenceError: require is not defined